# Use Adobe Air 3.3 SDK with Flash Builder

Tags: flash, air, adobe

Adobe Air SDK V3.3 was finally released june 8th 2012 and can be downloaded here: http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html

Now I am trying to use it within Flash Builder V4.6 by 'overlaying' the Adobe Air 3.3 SDK over a copy of the Flex V4.6.0 SDK in /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0/
Once I try to configure the overlayed SDK the Flash Builder complains that 'Directory does not contain a Flex SDK'

Anybody an idea on how to successfully get Flash Builder to use Adobe Air V3.3 SKD?

Answer (score 6):

For MAC users the best way is to copy the 4.6.0 folder and rename it in "4.6.0 + 3.3"
Then extract the AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2 file, go in it and rsync the content to the new sdk folder.

```
rsync ./* -avl /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks/4.6.0\ +\ 3.3/
```

Comment: Great idea using rsync! Note that it might need to be run under sudo

Comment: Nice, why did Adobe has not provided this command line. They are suggesting to manually go trough each folder and copy/replace file by file. +1 from me.

Answer (score 6):

### How to update Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 to AIR 3.5 SDK

Using these guidelines and elsewhere pages, I managed to update my installation. Thank you all, below are the details.

Download AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2 from http://www.adobe.com/special/products/air/sdk/

Decompress & untar the files (double click will do).

Navigate to /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks

Copy the existing 4.6.0 sdk folder and rename it as you wish. (e.g. 4.6.0_AIR3.5)

Navigate to the extracted AdobeAIRSDK folder and use rsync:

```
rsync ./* -avl /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.6/sdks/4.6.0_AIR3.5/
```

Check these files (inside frameworks folder) for references to the old player and version entries:

- air-config.xml
- airmobile-config.xml
- flex-config.xml

Update xml files:

```
<target-player>11.5</target-player>
<swf-version>18</swf-version>
```

In Flash Builder go to Preferences > Flash Builder > Installed Flex SDKs, add the new 4.6.0_AIR3.5 path, give it a name and make it the default sdk if you wish.

Don't forget to update your project xml namespace:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5">
```

Comment: +1. Thank you @cenk. I have spent a tremendous amount of time trying various ways of doing this. You'd think Adobe would have provided some guidance for this, since it isn't *at all* clear what to do. Your steps are complete, accurate, and clear. Bravo.

Answer (score 3):

merge in terminal 
tar jxvf AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2
Replace AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2 with the path to the downloaded AIR SDK tarball eg /User/XXXX/Downloads
Add the folder for the new player in SDK/frameworks/libs.player and call it 11.3 where you see 11.1 copy the playerglobal11_3.swc from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html and dont forget to update the argument in flash builder to include swf-version=16 to get all the goodies
And change the xml to target 3.3

Answer (score 1):

if you use a mac ! do NOT overwrite the folder. it will not just copy new files, it will do a complete replace of the sdk folder. So please enter each folder and copy/replace each file. Looks strange but this is how "mac" works.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it is incredibly time-consuming and painstaking, requiring you to go through all folders and nested subfolders and sub-sub folders. @cenk's solution takes about 1/100 of the time.

Comment: @David as long as his command line does not replace folders but just overwrites existing and copies new ones (as in Windows) I have no problem with cenk's solution and I do agree it takes much less time as manually doing it. Just wanted to point out that I did got the same issue as you by doing a wrong copy/overwrite.  PS: there are file manager tools which allow you to overwrite the folders under osX just like in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Some things never change, one of them is the lunar cycle, another is how Adobe perceives we should update AIR SDK's ...