# Installation of Adobe Air 3.7 SDK for Flex on Mac OS

Tags: macos, apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

It sounds so simple and probably should be, but I just spend 3 hours trying to get the most basic setup running and I'm lost in the mess Adobe created. I followed a couple of tutorials and documents but none seem to be working.

All I want is to generate a Flex for mobile project with the latest Air 3.7 SDK.

- I tried steps to replace the airsdk that is now deeply hidden in flashbuilders eclipse folders. That only allowed me to create an actionscript for mobile project with 3.7, but not a Flex project.
- I tried to download the Air sdk that supposed to be for flex developers (http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/mac/download/latest/AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2). I overlayed these files into an existing Flex 4.6.0 folder. The result was that Flashbuilder didn't recognize the folder as a Flex SDK anymore.

I also tried the latter step on a PC and it work so far that I can compile and debug flex for mobile apps on the ipad (with fast mode). Standard mode and export release build end in an never ending packaging process (1.5 hours now for a hello world app and still at 0%)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apache Flex has some scripts in the develop branch of the flex-sdk repo that will help you.

`git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk.git sdk

cd sdk

git checkout develop`

(The github mirror is a little out of date so can't post the direct links to the files sorry)

look in the ide directory and you'll see:

addAIRToSDK.sh - This downloads and merges an AIR SDK into an Flex SDK
checkAllPlayerGlobals.sh - Checks and downloads all versions of playerglobal.swc
setFlahsPlayerVerion.sh - Sets the minimum flash player version in a Flex SDK

The scripts support AIR 3.7 and Flash Player 11.7.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was to copy the files from the AIRSDK into the Flex SDK folder. This will work on a PC, but the macOS Finder does not merge folders as expected and eventually files get deleted.

The correct way to merge the folders is to use recync as explained in this post
[Use Adobe Air 3.3 SDK with Flash Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975151/use-adobe-air-3-3-sdk-with-flash-builder?rq=)