# Where is Adobe AIR install located?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, installation, adobe

At the moment I'm running Adobe AIR 3.2. I've previously tried installing 3.6 (and now 3.7) but I couldn't locate it. It's on my Mac somewhere but I can't find the file/folder to link it in Flash! In Flash I can only see a Target for `AIR 3.2 for iOS` in the settings.

There's a folder called 'AIR3.2' in my Applications folder:
~/Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/AIR 3.2/

I can't find where the 'AIR3.7' folder is?? I've looked in my Library following the instructions from this [page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/publishing-adobe-air-desktop.html#id_99618) and the [link seen on that page](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/troubleshoot-air-installation-mac-os.html) but can't find it. I've found a plist:
~/Library/Frameworks/Adobe AIR.framework/Versions/1.0/Resources/Info.plist
and inside it it says:
    `CFBundleVersion 3.7.0.1620`

Where can I find the folder so I can go into Flash CS6 -> Help -> Manage AIR SDK to add the new version?

Comment: Shouldnt you be selecting a folder (ie: the root of the downloaded SDK), not a particular file - i may be wrong, i dont use flash pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Adobe AIR Updater it only updates the runtime, not the SDK. You need to download the new SDK separately from Adobe: http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html

Answer (score 0):

Updating AIR SDK is not as your thought in your question. Explained step by step.

here is the [Installation of Adobe AIR SDK](http://www.air-tutorial.com/installing-air-sdk) . I hope you will fix your issue with this

Also you can check this question related to your [Installation of Adobe Air 3.7 SDK for Flex on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950945/installation-of-adobe-air-3-7-sdk-for-flex-on-mac-os)