# Update Flash Builder 4.6 to Air 15 on Mac

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I cannot find a coherent explanation of how to overlay air 15 onto Flash Builder 4.6.

Does someone know how to do this?  On [this page](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html) there are three options, but it isn't clear which one to select. It refers to 'for Flex Builders' but if Adobe renamed Flex some years ago to Flash Builder, why are they still calling it Flex? Is that the one to select?

If so, once it is selected, then what exactly are the steps to extract it? Adobe's instructions on [this page](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html) say

> Mac OS: In Terminal, cd to the root directory of the Flex SDK and run
>   this command:

```
tar jxvf AIR34_mac_sdk_XXXXXX.tbz2
```

> If you have trouble overwriting files due to file permissions, try
>   this command:

```
sudo tar jxvf AIR34_mac_sdk_XXXXXX.tbz2
```

What is the root directory of the Flex SDK? In my Properties --> Build Path --> Library Path in Flash Builder my path shows Flex 4.6.0(build 23201) - /Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0_AIR4.0  so I cd'd there and tried both of the above suggestions.

The command I used was

```
  tar jxvf air15_sdk_mac.tbz2
```

and then I tried

```
 sudo tar jxvf air15_sdk_mac.tbz2
```

Result:

Error opening archive: Failed to open 'air15_sdk_mac.tbz2'

So neither worked.

Can someone post or point to clear step-by-step instructions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you need is the one under "AIR 15 SDK for Flex Developers".  The error message you're seeing when you try to untar the file indicates that tar can't find the file you downloaded.  Make sure you specify the full path of the downloaded file when you run tar.

It's also a good idea to back up the Flex SDK directory before you start; copying the "AIR 15 SDK & Compiler Beta" download file over your Flex directory will break the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right file. The best step-by-step description that I have found is by @cenk, here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975151/use-adobe-air-3-3-sdk-with-flash-builder/ This refers to an earlier version but still works. Note that in the app descriptor file you must update the AIR version to 15.0  I tried 15 but that gave an error. Whoever downvoted this question has no idea how many people find this confusing. Just google.